# Convert a countdown like date format to milliseconds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I have to convert this countdown-like `Date` format `0d0h0m0s` to milliseconds. The format can optionally have `0d`, `0h`, `0m` heading values, hence admitted values are

```
1d23h10m
0d12h0m
12h0m
0m0s
0m10s
10s
```

while at least one trailing `0s` format value is required, the `0` value is optional for each of the `dhm` formats, so `0m5s` and `5s` are both admitted values.

Since this function will be applied N times per sec. (N between 10 and 100), there is a performances constraint for each function execution time.

**NOTE**. It's possible to use a simple `Regex` pattern to split the string like `/[dhms]/gi` into date components for `day`, `hour`, `minutes` and `seconds`, but I was looking to a date formatting safe approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to extract all matches with a regular expression, and then multiply and sum as needed:

```js
const re = /(?:(\d+)y)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:(\d+)d)?(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:(\d+)s)?/;
const toSeconds = input => {
  const [, years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds] = input.match(re);
  // console.log({years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds})
  const totalDays = ((years || 0) * 365)
    + ((months || 0) * 30)
    + (days || 0);
  const totalSeconds = totalDays * 24 * 3600
    + ((hours || 0)*3600)
    + ((minutes || 0) * 60)
    + (seconds || 0)
  return totalSeconds * 1000;
};
`1d23h10m
0d12h0m
12h0m
0m0s
0m10s
10s`.split('\n').forEach(str => console.log(toSeconds(str)));
```

Of course, if you want a different calculation (such as 365.25 days per year, or something like that), such a tweak would be quite easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Given the strings are short, a simple character parser is a practical alternative to using a regular expression. The following is compliant back to ECMAScript 2011:

```js
function parseTime(s) {
  var tokens = {d:8.64e7, h:3.6e6, m:6e4, s:1e3};
  var buff = '';
  return s.split('').reduce(function (ms, c) {
    c in tokens? (ms += buff * tokens[c]) && (buff = '') : buff += c;
    return ms;
  }, 0);
}
  
// Examples
['1d23h10m','0d12h0m','12h0m','0m0s','0m10s','10s','1d1s'].forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s + ' => ' + parseTime(s));
});
```

Comment: thanks, it would be interesting to evaluate performances between the two solutions, since I'm going to parse this output from a socket server, n times per sec, adding some constraints at the questions.